# Connect to mysql/mariadb with ssl and certs in go

Tags: mysql, go, ssl, mariadb, client-certificates

There are many examples on how to connect to a mariadb/mysql database using go/golang when only username and password is needed. But I have not found an easy example where the client needs certificates (TLS/SSL) to connect.

This works for a vanilla connection

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
) 

// Test that db is usable
// prints current date & time to stdout
func queryDB(db *sql.DB) {
    // Query the database
    var result string
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT NOW()").Scan(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func main() {
    // generate connection string
    cs := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", "username", "password", "dbHost", "dbPort", "database")
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", cs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error %s when opening DB\n", err)
        log.Printf("%s", cs)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
    e := db.Ping()
    fmt.Println(cs, e)
    queryDB(db)
}
```

But if the client needs certs to connect, where do I put that information?

in my `my.cnf` it would be theese lines:

```
[mysql]
## MySQL Client Configuration ##
ssl-ca=cert/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=cert/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=cert/client-key.pem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use certs for authentication you have to create a `tls.Config` and then do a `mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tlsConf)` and add `"?tsl=custom"` to the connection string.

Where `tls` comes from `"crypto/tls"` and `mysql` is from `"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"`

A working example:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)


// path to cert-files hard coded
// Most of this is copy pasted from the internet
// and used without much reflection
func createTLSConf() tls.Config {

    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("cert/ca-cert.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
        log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
    }
    clientCert := make([]tls.Certificate, 0, 1)

    certs, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert/client-cert.pem", "cert/client-key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    clientCert = append(clientCert, certs)

    return tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            rootCertPool,
        Certificates:       clientCert,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true, // needed for self signed certs
    }
}


// Test that db is usable
// prints version to stdout
func queryDB(db *sql.DB) {
    // Query the database
    var result string
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT NOW()").Scan(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func main() {

    // When I realized that the tls/ssl/cert thing was handled separately
    // it became easier, the following two lines are the important bit
    tlsConf := createTLSConf()  
    err := mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tlsConf)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error %s when RegisterTLSConfig\n", err)
        return
    }

    // connection string (dataSourceName) is slightly different
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?tls=custom", "username", "password", "dbHost", "dbPort", "database")
    db1, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error %s when opening DB\n", err)
        log.Printf("%s", dsn)
        return
    }
    defer db1.Close()
    e := db1.Ping()
    fmt.Println(dsn, e)
    queryDB(db1)
}
```